Did Plato confuse FORM/essence/knowledge with genetically passed (built-in) instincts and reflexes?

The child makes the identification and the mind of the child is led
away from the knowledge of the pure essence of what a chair is.  The
child knows the essence of mother and father and table and tree and
all things before it is born but gets confused by people uttering
sounds...
https://www.qcc.cuny.edu/socialSciences/ppecorino/INTRO_TEXT/Chapter%202%20GREEKS/Socrates_death3.htm#:~:text=Plato%20accepted%20an%20idea%20that,used%20it%20to%20explain%20KNOWLEDGE.

Some animals get most of their knowledge genetically. For example, fish. It almost does not need parental teaching or learning by experience. Would Plato also apply FORMs to fish or tarantula knowledge about things (environment)?

it should come as no surprise that 4th Century BC Plato is outdated when it comes to cognitive psychology, cognitive science and neurology at large. We know for example that face recognition is hardwired into our brain, somewhat similar to what you describe about fishes. But most of the concepts we form are through our experience after birth: see a face, enjoy it -> recognise this face we see everyday -> associating the face with "mama" -> form the concept of "mama", only much later learn about sexual reproduction and border cases like surrogate pregnancy, early adoption, etc...

Plato did not speak English (as far as we know!!). The Greek  "εἶδος" is closest structurally to English essence. See this and this. Also chairs are absurdly strawman egs for form.  Either use love truth beauty justice... Or point line number for sensible(!¡!) egs of eidos

Also there's some truth in @armand outlook: viz. this is a very presentist view. Its like asking did Beethoven write boogie woogie. Except its an order of magnitude more: Beethoven was a 100 years before boogie woogie. Plato was 2000 before genetics

2000 years later, the arguments for the Existence of the Soul did not change much.

Meanwhile arguments against, or about how the question is undecidable and pointless have made huge progress.

For Plato knowledge is knowledge of the Forms, acquired through the dialectical process of the soul: thinking, reasoning. If so, the newborn baby does not acquire the "Form of the mother" (if any). See Theaetetus: "Theaetetus’ third proposal about how to knowledge is that it is true belief with an account." Forms are: 1. primary beings; 2. they have causal
responsibility; 3. they are objects of a knowledge of
a privileged sort.

(From my pov) What is the εἶδος of soul is an interesting but tantalizing question. After all we cam translate εἶδος as essence we can also replace souk by essence. In that form it becomes something like What is the most essential feature of the human?

As far as I know Plato never says that animals are incapable of knowing the forms, although he makes the converse statement that a human, in contrast to animals, is necessarily capable of knowing the forms (Phaedrus 249b). What he says in that passage is that a human must be able to translate sense perception into intelligible concepts. This is not what we call instinct.
Nor is instinct why Plato says the forms are known at birth. A child instinctively knows to suck when hungry, but in this way humans are no different than animals. But a human child, as opposed to animals, will grow to be capable of understanding math and dialectics; this capability doesn't enter the child at some discrete point in time, and therefore must have been present from before birth. This and other arguments can be found in Meno and Phaedo (72e), or expressed poetically in the above Phaedrus myth.
But in Phaedo (81d) and more elaborately in the same Phaedrus myth, human souls are depicted as entering animal bodies, and animal souls as entering human bodies (but only those that were originally human); possibly this is an acknowledgment of human-like knowledge in some animals, or a kind of spectrum of knowledge between humans and animals.
